# Formating string value in dataframe to convert it to html tag

Tags: python, html, pandas

I would like to format every string value in a pandas dataframe column.
I was looking in other posts and I found something like:

```
df['Col']=df['Col'].map('${:,.2f}'.format)
```

Let's say the value of every row in that column is "Hello".
Example:

```
A  B
1  "Hello"
2  "Hello"
```

The final output of every row would be:

```
f"<br> <a href={"Hello"} title= Link; style='background-color: orange'> Title </a> </br>"

A  B
1  "f"<br> <a href={"Hello"} title= Link; style='background-color: orange'> Title </a> </br>""
2  "f"<br> <a href={"Hello"} title= Link; style='background-color: orange'> Title </a> </br>""
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df["Col"].apply(lambda s: f"<br> <a href={s} title= Link; style='background-color: orange'> Title </a> </br>""
```

Comment: this is perfect and it actually works, but it shows the whole link and not the title "LINK" I put in my html tag? Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to build HTML objects with many or complex conditional statements you can use a [string `Template`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) via the standard library.

Create a sample dataframe with two columns, id and url.

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, "google.com"],[1, "bing.com"],[1, "duckduckgo.com"]], columns=['id', 'url'])
```

Write a simple function that returns a template with values substituted. This will allow you to add validation, error handling, etc while processing the values.

```
from string import Template
def value_to_html(value):
        t = Template('<br> <a href=$url title= Link; style="background-color: orange"> Title </a> </br>')
        return t.substitute(url=value)
```

Then use Pandas [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html?highlight=apply#pandas.DataFrame.apply) method to run the function for each row in the data frame. Remember, [DO NOT MODIFY THE OBJECT YOU ARE ITERATING OVER](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html?highlight=iterrows#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows). So best to add a new column to the dataframe.

```
df1['html'] = df1['url'].apply(lambda x: value_to_html(x))
```

Templating can get much more complex and if your application requires more control, check out the [python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) for more guidance.

Comment: Which library are you using?  name 'Template' is not defined. Is it a built-in python functionality?

Comment: Sorry my answer is not more clear. The stdlib string library contains the Template class. `from string import Template`